# Composer update hangs when upgrading Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

While upgrading from Laravel v6 to v7, `composer update` gets stuck at 'Updating dependencies'.
Running it in verbose mode gives me this message :

```
Looking at all rules.
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #4709)
```

It keeps on checking the rules (infinite passes).

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
        "beyonic/beyonic-php": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.12",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.31.0",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.17",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.4.1"
    },
   
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    }
```

Comment: what is your laravel version laravel6 or laravel 7?

Comment: Please share more details. Which versions of PHP and Composer are you using?

Comment: It could also help to use more up-to-date version constraints here and there, such that the dependency resolve does not have to check **all** conditions (for example, the latest release that matches `nunomaduro/collision: ^2.0` is more than two years old)

Comment: I'm using PHP v7.4.3 and Composer v2.0.14

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies are not compatible after we upgrade the version of Laravel. According to Laravel document, you must upgrade the version of the following dependencies.
(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies)

```
laravel/framework to ^7.0
nunomaduro/collision to ^4.1
phpunit/phpunit to ^8.5
laravel/tinker to ^2.0
facade/ignition to ^2.0
```

**Note:**

You should also check the versions of the remaining dependencies.